# How to make "strtok function" work with more than one Token String at a time?  Would function pointers solve this?

Tags: c++, c

`strtok` function uses a static variable for parsing the string into tokens.  So this causes a conflict when multiple calls are done.  Other than using threads how could I do the following:  thx
- Can I use a function pointer to allocate the function at 2 different places?  Would this make the static variable inside "strtok" allocate at 2 different places?

```
//breaking up first by Sentence and than by Word.
char phrase[] = "My dog has fleas.\nAnd he gave them to me."; 
char del1[]   = "\n";
char del2[]   = " ";
char *token1;
char *token2;


token1 = strtok( phrase, del1);

while( token1 != NULL )
{
    printf("Sentence:  %s",token1);

    token2 = strtok( token1, del2);
    while( token2 != NULL ){
        token2 = strtok( NULL, del2);
        printf("WORD:  %s",token2);
    }

    token1 = strtok( NULL, del1);
}
```

Comment: `My dog has flees`? What is a flee? Haha, fixed the grammar in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `strtok`, perhaps use `strsep`.  Note that I have extracted the nested loop into a function - nested loops suck!

EDITED: changed to use `strsep` directly

```
/* print each word in a string*/
static void print_words(char *s)
{
    while (s && *s) {
        char *t = strsep(&s, " ");
        printf("WORD:  %s\n", t);
    }
}

void loop(void)
{
    /* duplicate string in case it is read-only */
    char *phrase = strdup("My dog has flees.\nAnd he gave them to me.");

    while (phrase) {
        char *s = strsep(&phrase, "\n");
        printf("Sentence:  %s\n", s);
        print_words(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `strsep()` has different behavior than `strtok()` when there is a run of delimiter characters (`strtok()` treats a run as a single field separator, `strsep()` treats a run of delimiters as several empty fields).  Which behavior you might want depends on your needs.  `strsep()` is also not available in VC++6 (which is what the OP apparently wants), though it has a pretty simple implementation (same problem as for for `strtok_r()`.

Comment: In case the OP wants to use `strsep()` with VC++6, a public domain version can be found here: http://unixpapa.com/incnote/string.html

Comment: I edited the code example to use `strsep` directly instead of via another function (which I had carelessly extracted from some other code without checking that it was needed).

Comment: It's easy to get `strtok`-like behavior from `strsep`, but impossible to go the other way, which is why we made `strsep` behave the way it does.  (Just add:  `if (*phrase == '\0') continue;` or similar to skip empty "tokens".)  Slogan: `strsep` ain't great, but it's better than `strtok`. :-)

Comment: @chris: good point. I guess I was just considering the code as posted.

Answer (score 6):

use `strtok_r()` (re-entrant version).

Comment: what header file holds this?  Will this work is Visual c++ 6.0?

Comment: strtok_r is in `<string.h>` header file.

Comment: In standard C, it's in string.h (cstring). You may have to lookup manuals for vc++.

Comment: (Visual c++ 6.0) I opened string.h... and I don't see strtok_r ... only strtok.

Comment: I am wanting to do this with out using MFC!

Comment: I see similar functions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx But I can't find their descriptions to know what they do.

Comment: @jdl: Here's a public domain `strtok_r()` implementation that should work fine in VC6: http://snipplr.com/view/16918/strtokr/

Comment: [Here's an example using strtok_r](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10349288/1275169).

Answer (score 1):

Use strtok_r(). It takes one more parameter - pointer which acts like a context.

Answer (score 1):

Is that C or C++?

If it is C++, you can use `std::string` instead of `char *` and `std::string` methods to achieve the same result as you get using `strtok`.

For example you could get benefits from `find` and `substr` methods.