# How can I split a C-string twice with strtok in C?

Tags: c, string, strtok

Assume that we have a C string

```
text = "0.4,0.1,-4.1#100,200,300#-32.13,23.41,100#<...>#20,25,30"
```

The goal is to split that string first with `#` and then `,` because I'm after each values between `#` and there are three separate values between `,`.

The string `text` contains 17 elements of 3 numbers with separator `,` and 16 elements of `#`

I did try to solve this with this code.

```
char *min_max_bias_char;
float min_max_bias_float[3*17]; /* 3 values per each analog input channel */
for(uint8_t i = 0; i <= 16; i++) {
    if(i == 0)
        min_max_bias_char = strtok(text, DELIMITER);
    else
        min_max_bias_char = strtok(NULL, DELIMITER);
    min_max_bias_float[0 + i*3] = atoff(strtok(min_max_bias_char, ",")); /* Min value */
    min_max_bias_float[1 + i*3] = atoff(strtok(NULL, ","));              /* Max value */
    min_max_bias_float[2 + i*3] = atoff(strtok(NULL, ","));              /* Bias value */
}
```

Where I first split the text string `text` depending on `#` and then I take the first index of `min_max_bias_char` and split that on the delimiter `,`.

This did not work out very well because as soon I do `strtok(min_max_bias_char)` then `strtok` forget about the `min_max_bias_char = strtok(NULL, DELIMITER);` statement.

Now I got the array `min_max_bias_float` that holds the values inside of an array `{0.4,0.1,-4.1,100,200,300,-32.13,23.41,100,<...>,20,25,30}`

This is the output.
So how can I solve this issue?
I'm trying to split string twice.

Comment: I'm not really clear what output you want. Can you provide simple untruncated input and unabridged output? Can you show text and perhaps a function header in the interests of a [mcve]? Thanks.

Comment: You can't nest `strtok()` because the inner loop destroys the state of the outer loop. You need to use `strtok_r()` so you can maintain separate states.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! `strtok_r` might be the solution for me.

Comment: Actually, it's easier than that. I'm writing an answer now.

Comment: If you just want a contiguous array of results, why not `strtok` on [multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597977/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-using-strtok-in-c), e.g. `"#,"`? It should be pretty easy to do with a plain loop too.

Comment: What is `atoff()`? The name of the function is `atof()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtok` accepts [multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597977/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-using-strtok-in-c), and since your data structure seems to not care whether the current element is a `','` or a `'#'` character (in other words, you're not building a 2d structure requiring nested looping), you can just provide a delimiter string and make one call to `strtok` in the loop.

Here's a minimal example you can adapt to your environment:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char delimiters[] = "#,";
    char text[] = "0.4,0.1,-4.1#100,200,300#-32.13,23.41,100#20,25,30";
    int size = 3 * 4; // or 3 * 17;
    float res[size];
    res[0] = atof(strtok(text, delimiters));

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        res[i] = atof(strtok(NULL, delimiters));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%.2f ", res[i]);
    }

    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0.40 0.10 -4.10 100.00 200.00 300.00 -32.13 23.41 100.00 20.00 25.00 30.00
```

It's a good idea to check the return value of `strtok` in the above code.

If you want to avoid `strtok` (there are [good reasons to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44336831/6243352)), there's `strtok_r` or write it by hand with a loop:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char delimiters[] = "#,";
    char text[] = "0.4,0.1,-4.1#100,200,300#-32.13,23.41,100#20,25,30";
    int size = 3 * 4; // or 3 * 17;
    float res[size];
    int res_size = 0;
    int last_index = 0;

    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(text); i < len; i++) {
        if (!strchr(delimiters, text[i])) {
            continue;
        }
        else if (i - last_index >= 32 || res_size >= size) {
            fprintf(stderr, "buffer size exceeded\n");
            return 1;
        }
        
        char buf[32] = {0};
        strncpy(buf, text + last_index, i - last_index);
        res[res_size++] = atof(buf);
        last_index = i + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < res_size; i++) {
        printf("%.2f ", res[i]);
    }

    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need nested uses of `strtok()`. Just alternate your delimiters: 2 commas followed by 1 hash each time through the main loop.

```
char *curptr = text;
for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    min_max_bias_float[0 + i*3] = atoff(strtok(curptr, ","));
    min_max_bias_float[1 + i*3] = atoff(strtok(NULL, ","));
    min_max_bias_float[2 + i*3] = atoff(strtok(NULL, DELIMITER));
    curptr = NULL; // so subsequent loops will continue using the same string
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answr. Sorry, that example did not work. Have a look at my answer :)

Comment: After your edit, it's much better. But `min_max_bias_float[0 + i*3] == 0` when `i = 1`. It should be a value grater than zero in my case.

Comment: `min_max_bias_float[3] == 100.0` when I tested it.

Comment: Here is how my string looks like. The `Å` is my delimiter in my case. https://pastebin.com/rsDx2rxW

Comment: When I run your code, I'm missing `-20.000000`

Comment: There's no `-20` in your sample data.

Comment: The first 9 values in my array are `0.40 0.10 -4.10
100.00 200.00 300.00
-32.13 23.41 100.00`

Comment: Oh, that was just en example C string.

Comment: There may be an issue with multibyte characters. I used `#` as the delimiter and it works fine.

Comment: I'm getting an "invalid character encoding" error when I try to use that character in my source code, I need to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Never mind, it was just a warning. The program still works.

Comment: I think you can try UTF-8? Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: I was using an ancient version of Emacs.

Comment: I recommend Eclipse. Fantastic IDE.

Comment: I use PHPStorm and CLion for my real work. Emacs is just for throwaway stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You have useful tips in comments, and useful answers already.

Anyway, I will point you to use a **state machine**. It is a common and perhaps easy way to express this kind of problem.

In this example case it is a minimal one, with only 2 states.

**Below is a complete C program, after some discussion :)**

### about the data

If I understand it correctly you have a number of fields, 3 `doubles` in this case, separated by `,` and forming a group. And each group is surrounded or at least terminated by `#`. The number of groups is not fixed.

It would be good to have a function that gets a line, parses it and get the values in some useful and ready to use way. So at first I would look to the data

#### the group

```
typedef struct { double field[3]; } Group;
```

#### the result set

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned n_groups; // # of 3-doubles groups
    unsigned n_incr; // size of increment block
    int      n_size; // # of pointers to Group. Error code is <0
    Group*   g; // the groups

}   Set;
```

The `Set` constains an array of `Group`. Each `Group` has the 3 doubles. The array should be created dynamically, since the number of groups is not known. The array is allocated in group of `n_incr`, and the actual size is in kept in `n_size`. Fairly common.

And it seems convenient, since you can iterate over the results with ease, or save them for future reference. See the code to show a set *on-screen*:

```
void        print_set(Set* set)
{
    printf("set: %d groups:\n", set->n_groups);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < set->n_groups; i += 1)
        printf("%3d: %.2f, %.2f, %.2f\n", 1 + i,
            set->g[i].field[0],
            set->g[i].field[1],
            set->g[i].field[2]);
};
```

That shows, for the line

```
        "0.4,0.1,-4.1#100,200,300#-32.13,23.41,100#20,25,30",
```

after parse:

```
set: 4 groups:
  1: 0.40, 0.10, -4.10
  2: 100.00, 200.00, 300.00
  3: -32.13, 23.41, 100.00
  4: 20.00, 25.00, 30.00
```

#### A function to get a Result set from a string

```
    int         parse(const char*,Set*); // parse string into set
```

You pass a string and a `Set` as above and get in the set the parsed arguments, and a 0 return code in case of success.

#### helper functions

To make it easier, since it is an example, the program uses these functions

```
    Set*        build_set(unsigned);
    Set*        free_set(Set*);
    Set*        insert(Group*, Set*);  // insert group into set
    int         parse(const char*,Set*); // parse string into set
    void        print_set(Set*);
```

with the (I believe) obvious effects. The parameter in `build_set()` is the size of the block of parameters to be created and of each extension if needed.
`free_set()` releases memory in the correct order, `insert()` inserts a group into the result set, `print_set()` shows them on-screen, and `parse()` is the actual parser.

#### `main()` for a test

The example code takes an array of strings and parses them all, using the functions above:

```
int         main(void)
{
    // a few tests
    const char* test[] = {
        "0.4,0.1,-4.1#100,200,300#-32.13,23.41,100#20,25,30", 
        "#0.4,0.1,-4.1#100,200,300#-32.13,23.41,100#20,25,30#",
        "1.1,-2.2,3.3",
        "#1,2,3,4#", NULL};

    // parse all tests

    for (int i = 0; test[i] != NULL; i += 1)
    {
        printf("About to parse \"%s\"\n", test[i]);
        Set* values = build_set(10);
        int res = parse(test[i], values);
        printf("\nparse() returned %d, found %d groups\n",
               res, values->n_groups);
        print_set(values);
        values = free_set(values);
        printf("\n\tAnswer set free()'d\n\n");
    };  // for()
    return 0;
}
```

The logic is simple: for each line:

- build a set using blocks of 10 groups in it
- parse the string using the actual function
- show the result set
- releases the memory and invalidates the pointer

You can edit the array `test[]` and try another sets. Just keep the `NULL` at the end. The strings in the tests are from your code, in fact, and an invalid line with 4 doubles at the end.

#### test output

```
About to parse "0.4,0.1,-4.1#100,200,300#-32.13,23.41,100#20,25,30"

parse() returned 0, found 4 groups
set: 4 groups:
  1: 0.40, 0.10, -4.10
  2: 100.00, 200.00, 300.00
  3: -32.13, 23.41, 100.00
  4: 20.00, 25.00, 30.00

        Answer set free()'d

About to parse "#0.4,0.1,-4.1#100,200,300#-32.13,23.41,100#20,25,30#"

parse() returned 0, found 4 groups
set: 4 groups:
  1: 0.40, 0.10, -4.10
  2: 100.00, 200.00, 300.00
  3: -32.13, 23.41, 100.00
  4: 20.00, 25.00, 30.00

        Answer set free()'d

About to parse "1.1,-2.2,3.3"

parse() returned 0, found 1 groups
set: 1 groups:
  1: 1.10, -2.20, 3.30

        Answer set free()'d

About to parse "#1,2,3,4#"

parse() returned -4, found 0 groups
set: 0 groups:

        Answer set free()'d
```

#### The complete program

```
#define ST_INIT 0
#define ST_INFIELD 1

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct { double field[3]; } Group;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned n_groups; // # of 3-doubles groups
    unsigned n_incr; // size of increment block
    int      n_size; // # of pointers to Group. Error code is <0
    Group*   g; // the groups

}   Set;

Set*        build_set(unsigned);
Set*        free_set(Set*);
Set*        insert(Group*, Set*);  // insert group into set
int         parse(const char*,Set*); // parse string into set
void        print_set(Set*);

int         main(void)
{
    // a few tests
    const char* test[] = {
        "0.4,0.1,-4.1#100,200,300#-32.13,23.41,100#20,25,30", 
        "#0.4,0.1,-4.1#100,200,300#-32.13,23.41,100#20,25,30#",
        "1.1,-2.2,3.3",
        "#1,2,3,4#", NULL};

    // parse all tests

    for (int i = 0; test[i] != NULL; i += 1)
    {
        printf("About to parse \"%s\"\n", test[i]);
        Set* values = build_set(10);
        int res = parse(test[i], values);
        printf("\nparse() returned %d, found %d groups\n",
               res, values->n_groups);
        print_set(values);
        values = free_set(values);
        printf("\n\tAnswer set free()'d\n\n");
    };  // for()
    return 0;
}


Set*        build_set(unsigned block)
{   // block is # of groups
    // allocated each time
    Set* set      = (Set*)malloc(sizeof(Set));
    set->n_groups = 0;
    set->n_incr   = block;
    set->n_size   = block;
    set->g        = (Group*)malloc(block * sizeof(Group));
    return set;
}


Set*        free_set(Set* set)
{
    if (set == NULL) return NULL;
    free(set->g);
    free(set);
    return NULL;
};


Set*        insert(Group* g, Set* s)
{
    // check for need of extension
    if (s->n_groups >= (unsigned)s->n_size)
    {  // Set if full: adds 1 block
        unsigned sz   = s->n_size + s->n_incr;
        Group*   temp = (Group*)realloc( s->g, sz * sizeof(Group));
        if (temp == NULL) return NULL;
        s->g = temp;  // extended
        s->n_size = sz;
    };  // if()
    s->g[s->n_groups].field[0] = g->field[0];
    s->g[s->n_groups].field[1] = g->field[1];
    s->g[s->n_groups].field[2] = g->field[2];
    s->n_groups += 1;
    return s;
};


int         parse(const char* text, Set* set)
{
    if (text == NULL) return -1;
    char     line[30];
    char state = ST_INIT;
    unsigned ix    = 0;
    unsigned i_f   = 0; // inside field
    unsigned n_f   = 0; // # of fields in the group
    Group    grp;
    while (1)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case ST_INIT:
                switch (text[ix])
                {
                    case 0:
                        return -2;  // empty
                        break;
                    case ',':
                        return -30;
                        break;
                    case '#':  // start at #
                        state = ST_INFIELD;
                        break;
                    default:
                        line[i_f++] = text[ix];
                        state       = ST_INFIELD;
                        break;
                };  // switch()
                ix += 1;

            case ST_INFIELD:
                switch (text[ix])
                {
                    case 0:  // end of text: should have 0 or 3 fields
                        if (i_f == 0) return 0;  // normal end
                        if (n_f != 2) return -3;
                        line[i_f] = 0;       // terminate string
                        grp.field[n_f] = atof(line);
                        //printf("Field: %d, from \"%s\" = %f\n", n_f,
                        //       line, grp.field[n_f]);
                        insert(&grp, set);
                        return 0;
                        break;
                    case ',':                    // end of field
                        if (n_f > 1) return -4;  // misplaced
                        // must have 3 fields
                        line[i_f]      = 0;
                        grp.field[n_f] = atof(line);
                        //printf("Field: %d, from \"%s\" = %f\n", n_f,
                        //       line, grp.field[n_f]);
                        n_f += 1;
                        i_f = 0;
                        if (n_f == 3)
                        {
                            insert(&grp, set);
                            n_f = 0;
                            i_f = 0;
                        }
                        break;
                    case '#':                     // group terminator #
                        if (n_f != 2) return -5;  // must have 3 fields
                        line[i_f]      = 0;       // terminate string
                        grp.field[n_f] = atof(line);
                        //printf("Field: %d, from \"%s\" = %f\n", n_f,
                        //       line, grp.field[n_f]);
                        n_f += 1;
                        i_f = 0;
                        if (n_f == 3)
                        {
                            n_f = 0;
                            i_f = 0;
                            insert(&grp, set);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        line[i_f++] = text[ix];
                        break;
                };  // switch()
                ix += 1;
        };  // switch()
    };  // while()
    return 0;
}


void        print_set(Set* set)
{
    printf("set: %d groups:\n", set->n_groups);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < set->n_groups; i += 1)
        printf("%3d: %.2f, %.2f, %.2f\n", 1 + i,
            set->g[i].field[0],
            set->g[i].field[1],
            set->g[i].field[2]);
};

/*
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68584131/
how-can-i-split-a-c-string-twice-with-strtok-in-c
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, thanks to `strtok_r`

```
/* Collect */
char *min_max_bias_char;
char *text_pointer = text;
float min_max_bias_float[3*17]; /* 3 values per each analog input channel */
for(uint8_t i = 0; i <= 16; i++) {
    if(i == 0)
        min_max_bias_char = strtok_r(text, DELIMITER, &text_pointer);
    else
        min_max_bias_char = strtok_r(NULL, DELIMITER, &text_pointer);
    min_max_bias_float[0 + i*3] = atoff(strtok(min_max_bias_char, ",")); /* Min value */
    min_max_bias_float[1 + i*3] = atoff(strtok(NULL, ","));              /* Max value */
    min_max_bias_float[2 + i*3] = atoff(strtok(NULL, ","));              /* Bias value */
}
```

Comment: Is `i = 20` a typo?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry! I accidentally placed a `2` before the `0`.