# Vector of comma separated token to const char**

Tags: c++, arrays, string, stdvector, boost-tokenizer

I am trying to convert a comma separated string to vector of const char*. With the following code, by expected output is

```
ABC_
DEF
HIJ
```

but I get

```
HIJ
DEF
HIJ
```

Where am I going wrong?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string s("ABC_,DEF,HIJ");
   typedef boost::char_separator<char> char_separator;
   typedef boost::tokenizer<char_separator> tokenizer;

   char_separator comma(",");
   tokenizer token(s, comma);
   tokenizer::iterator it;

   vector<const char*> cStrings;

   for(it = token.begin(); it != token.end(); it++)
   {
      //cout << (*it).c_str() << endl;
      cStrings.push_back((*it).c_str());
   }

   std::vector<const char*>::iterator iv;
   for(iv = cStrings.begin(); iv != cStrings.end(); iv++)
   {
      cout << *iv << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/3tvnUs

EDIT:
Solution with help of answers below:
(PaulMcKenzie offers a neater solution using lists.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

char* createCopy(std::string s, std::size_t bufferSize)
{
   char* value = new char[bufferSize];
   memcpy(value, s.c_str(), (bufferSize - 1));
   value[bufferSize - 1] = 0;
   return value;
}

int main()
{
   string s("ABC_,DEF,HIJ");
   typedef boost::char_separator<char> char_separator;
   typedef boost::tokenizer<char_separator> tokenizer;

   char_separator comma(",");
   tokenizer token(s, comma);
   tokenizer::iterator it;

   vector<const char*> cStrings;

   for(it = token.begin(); it != token.end(); it++)
   {
      //cout << it->c_str() << endl;
      cStrings.push_back(createCopy(it->c_str(),
                                      (it->length() + 1)));
   }

   std::vector<const char*>::iterator iv;
   for(iv = cStrings.begin(); iv != cStrings.end(); iv++)
   {
      cout << *iv << endl;
   }

   //delete allocations by new
   //...
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not an array of `std::string`?

Comment: I need to later pass this on to a library which can only accept a `const char**`; I pass this vector as `&vector[0]`.

Comment: be aware that your signature of createCopy requires creating a copy of string twice, as it takes a copy of string. You probably want this function to take `const char*` as an argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the thing: `boost::tokenizer::iterator` doesn't return you ownership of a copy of the string, but a refernce to an internal copy.

For example, after running your code I get:

```
HIJ
HIJ
HIJ
```

the solution is to replace `cStrings.push_back((*it).c_str())` with one of the following:

```
    char* c = new char[it->length() + 1];
    c[it->length()] = 0;
    cStrings.push_back(c);
    std::strncpy(c, it->c_str(), it->length());
```

doesn't look pretty, but you probably won't get faster than that (at least if you want to use `boost::tokenizer`.

other option is to totally replace `boost::tokenizer` with e.g. `strtok` - an example can be found here: [C split a char array into different variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349270/c-split-a-char-array-into-different-variables)

you can also use `boost::algorithm::string::split`, but then you might need to remap `string` to `const char*` later on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that doesn't require dynamic allocation, and at the same time give you the std::vector that you're looking for.  The trick is to create your arguments in "permanent" storage, and then just set the vector of pointers to this storage.

The code below uses `std::list` for the permanent storage.  The reason why is that we can guarantee that the iterators to the items in the `std::list` do not become invalidated when we add items to the list container.  This is a necessary requirement when building the final vector of `const char *`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <list>

typedef std::vector<char> CharArray;
typedef std::list<CharArray> StringList;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   StringList sList;

   string s("ABC_,DEF,HIJ");
   typedef boost::char_separator<char> char_separator;
   typedef boost::tokenizer<char_separator> tokenizer;

   char_separator comma(",");
   tokenizer token(s, comma);
   tokenizer::iterator it;

   vector<const char*> cStrings;

   for(it = token.begin(); it != token.end(); ++it)
   {
        // create an array of char and place on list
        sList.push_back(CharArray(it->begin(), it->end()));

        // null terminate this entry
        sList.back().push_back(0);

        // add the pointer to this entry to the vector of const char *.
        cStrings.push_back(&sList.back()[0]);
   }

   std::vector<const char*>::iterator iv;
   for(iv = cStrings.begin(); iv != cStrings.end(); iv++)
   {
      cout << *iv << endl;
   }
}
```

Note that we don't have to dynamically allocate memory here.  The only thing you need to ensure is that the `StringList` doesn't go out of scope, since this is where your arguments are found.

Comment: CharArray is likely to dynamically allocate memory, although you're right that small vector optimization may go in handy here.

Comment: Yes, CharArray internally handles the memory, but that is the difference between doing that, and having to manage the memory yourself.  The code above is guaranteed not to leak.

Comment: that's true, but at the expense of bookkeeping two lists. It's in fact equal to copying to `std::vector<std::string>` and then taking `c_str`. It doesn't need to be a problem of course.