# How to read from an .ini file?

Tags: c, configuration, ini

I have created a basic `.ini` file called `configuration.ini`. This file looks as follows:

```
[Application]
no_of_applications= 4;

[states]

title = "Config File States available";
name = 'Active, Deactivated, Hot';

[reaction]
reac_type = ["switch_schedule", "activate_app", "disable_app";
```

Now I intend to read this .ini file from my C program. I have included the `#include <configuration.ini>` line in my C program. I just want to read the title from the section 'states' in the C program i.e

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<configuration.ini>

int main()
{
    //read the variable 'title' from 'states' and print it
    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody tell me how can I do that?

Comment: You may want to consider **not** reinventing the wheel, and use [one of many existing parsers](https://github.com/ndevilla/iniparser)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: I tried using the the iniparser. But the problem is I was not able to install it onto the Eclipse CDT platform on my Laptop. Perhaps you could send me a link where doing this has been explained? I would be thankful :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using Windows, you can work this way:

First include `Windows.h`

```
#include <Windows.h>
```

On your function, create a `LPCSTR` (heh!? Really? Yeah.)

```
LPCSTR ini = "C:\\config.ini";
```

And call [`GetPrivateProfileString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724353(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
char returnValue[100];
GetPrivateProfileString("states", "title", 0, returnValue, 100, ini);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that.. But according to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724366%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) aren't the arguments too less for GetPrivateProfileString?

Comment: @AnamikaAna yeah. I left the return value out

Comment: thank you for that. :) I worked and I could print the title. I had one more question. If I wanted to print instead of the whole name i.e 'Active, Deactivated, Hot' , i just want to print the term 'Hot', how can I do that? Is it like I access an array?

Comment: @AnamikaAna You'll have to split it out based on a delimiter. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349270/c-split-a-char-array-into-different-variables)

Answer (score 4):

Well, first of all, do not `#include` the `.ini` file. It does not think what you think it does. `#include <fname>` actually *adds* the content of the file `fname` to the current file, which is not what you want. Remove the `#include`.

Secondly,  be it `.ini` or something else, if it is having formatted text, you can always use the below algorithm to read the file.

1. Define a buffer long enough to hold an entire *line*.
2. Open the file using [`fopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen). Check against errors.
3. Read a line from the file using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets). Check for success.
4. Compare the read line with your section value, for example, `"[states]"`. You may want to get rid of the trailing `newline` read by the `fgets()` first.
5. - If it matches, read the next line and continue to step 6.
   - If it does not match, continue to step 3.
6. Tokenize the input using [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok).
7. Check the first token against your expected *head* value, for example, `title` here. You may use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).
8. If it matches, tokenize the **same** input string to get the next token, which is your expected value.

Comment: Fopen with "r" mode ?

Comment: @uditr043 as per the requirement here, yes.